# What's the word 'gin'?

Tags: meaning

A quote from George Orwell's book 1984:

> “Winston roused himself and sat up straighter. He let out a belch. The gin was rising from his stomach.”

I read that gin is an alcoholic drink and a game, but I don't think Orwell is referring to that.

Comment: It is definitely referring to an alcoholic drink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text can be found here. [Nineteen Eighty-four, by George Orwell](https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/o/orwell/george/o79n/chapter1.1.html)

In this case I am certain that it refers to the alcoholic drink. The author is using a clever writing technique that tells us Winston is a drinker (and possibly a heavy drinker) without saying it explicitly.

EDIT

I've just found confirmation:

> He was conscious of nothing except the blankness of the page in front
>   of him, the itching of the skin above his ankle, the blaring of the
>   music, and a slight booziness caused by the gin.